# I need help with doing two inductive proofs using integration by parts.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, integration-by-parts

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n - 1}x \, dx = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n + 1)}$$
I have made the integration by parts substitutions as follows:
$$u = \sin^{2n}(x) \text{ and } dv = \sin x\,dx$$

$$du = (2n)\sin(x)^{2n-1} \cos x \, dx$$

$$v = -\cos x$$

I am not sure if these are the correct substitutions to make and I am also unsure of the rest of the methods to complete the proof.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n x \, dx = \frac{n-1}{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n-2} x\,dx$$

$$u = \sin^{n-1} x \, dv = \sin x\,dx$$

$$du = (n-1)\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos x \, dx$$

$$v=-\cos x$$

I am pretty confident with these substitutions I just had a hard time with the rest of it.

Comment: @user190080 : If you want to clean up the MathJax usage, then the following isn't a really great place to leave it: $\int_0^{pi/2} \sin^{2n - 1}(x)dx = \frac{2*4*6***2n}{3*5*7***(2n + 1)}$.  I changed it to this: $$\int_0^{pi/2} \sin^{2n - 1}x \, dx = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n + 1)}$$ Note $\pi$ rather than $pi$ and $\text{“}\cdots\text{''}$ rather than $\text{“}***\text{''}$. Using an asterisk in this context is for situations when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard. You can write $4\cdot5$ or $4\times5$; there's no need for $4*5$. $\qquad$

Comment: Offtopic @MichaelHardy you're right, I should have had put a bit more time on editing this post - it just went through the first post queue and I was short on time and therefore my main concern was to make this post at least accessible and then improve it consecutively (also by other users), so yeah, a compromise....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\sin^{2n+1}x\,dx
&=\int\sin^{2n}x\sin x\,dx \\[6px]
&=-\cos x\sin^{2n}x+2n\int\cos^2x\sin^{2n-1}x\,dx \\[6px]
&=-\cos x\sin^{2n}x+2n\int\sin^{2n-1}x\,dx-2n\int\sin^{2n+1}x\,dx
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
(2n+1)\int\sin^{2n+1}x\,dx=
-\cos x\sin^{2n}x+2n\int\sin^{2n-1}x\,dx
$$
Hence
$$
(2n+1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}x\,dx=
\Bigl[-\cos x\sin^{2n}x\Bigr]_0^{\pi/2}+2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x\,dx
$$
and, finally,
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}x\,dx=
\frac{2n}{2n+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x\,dx
$$
Now apply the induction hypothesis.